# class browsing in django

Tags: python, django

I'd like to browse active classes in Django. I think I'd learn a lot that way. So what's a good way to do that?

I could use IDLE if I knew how to start Django from within IDLE. But as I'm new to Python/Django, I'm not particularly wedded to IDLE. Other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[playing with the API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api)

You can easily get a django project loaded in IDLE. All it needs is the project on `sys.path` and `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` set to the settings package.

E.g.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append("/path/to/parent") # under which myproject is hosted
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
import myproject.myapp.models # or whatever
```

Should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine what you mean by *class browsing*. If you are comfortable with the terminal you could try to inspect python/django objects via the shell and autocompletion.

```
$ ./manage shell
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Feb  6 2010, 01:49:44) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]: from your.app.models import *
In [2]: 
...
```

You may also like [this enhanced version of the Django shell](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/).

I also recommend the django documentation, e.g. if you like to learn about `Request` and `Response` objects:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#ref-request-response

How to enable tab-completion in the default python shell:

- http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.com/2009/09/tab-completion-in-python-shell-how-to.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked the question because I'm not thrilled with the quality of the documentation. It seems disjointed. For a simple example, I tried a google search on "django http response" expecting to be sent to a Django docs page that, among other things would tell me what I needed to IMPORT to access that class. I was sent to this page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest and no mention of the actual IMPORT statement needed to access.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding [django-command-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) addon application and then using:

```
  ./manage.py shell_plus
```

which loads all models from all applications at startup, saving a lot of time on typing "from myapp.models import MyModel"

And of course [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org) - which is used by `shell_plus` if found - is superior to the default shell.